# Debugging Styling In An Email

Tags: css, email

I have a system that sends emails to people. And because it is an email, I have to make all styling inline.

The styling is great and looks like the designs on all devices, except for android lollipop and onwards. (Testing this on "email on acid").

The styling is also fine on a browser but email styling is wrong.

How can I debug this? On a browser, I can use inspect element, but I can't do that with emails. Is there a tool that could help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check all the styles that are supported by devices here:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thank. I've seen loads of tables that show compatibility, but it would make things easier if I could 'inspect element' and edit the DOM directly. It's a large amount of styling so debugging by going through a guide is very difficult.

Comment: No worries.  You might find the suspect elements in that table.